# XML embedded in Python docstring, use syntax highlighting

Tags: python, xml, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on a Python project where there are some blocks of XML defined inside docstrings.

The code contains strings like this

```
xml_str = """<a>
    <b>text</b>
</a>"""
```

In reality, the blocks of embedded XML are much larger. The problem is this XML becomes difficult to read. Since an IDE renders the XML as a String in one color, the text cannot be visually parsed as easily as if it had normal XML syntax highlighting applied.

I'm looking for an editor which will either natively support syntax highlighting in Strings, or where such a feature can be hacked in easily. This feature would be really cool to have, so I'm prepared to invest some time to make it happen.

I realize there are some arguments for why embedding XML in such a manner would be bad practice. I would agree, except in this situation. I have found a way to solve a problem very effectively by placing XML in a Python file directly instead of into an external resource.

**Edit**

I normally use PyDev for Eclipse, so I would be biased to solutions using it. Although I am prepared to swtich IDEs for this project if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Use syntax highlighting plugin http://colorer.sf.net/eclipsecolorer/  for eclipse. It Automatic folding support for mostly all (200+) supported languages.